# Implementing REST using JDBC Tables

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http, esb

Currently we are implementing REST API's using the spring-boot. Since our API's are growing in number we are thinking of a solution to implement the REST API's using a different approach.

The approach is as below :

- Expose a single service to receive all the HTTP requests.
- We will have the URI's configured in a data base table to call the
  next set of services. These service are configured to listen to
  particular JMS messages.
- The next set of services will receive the JMS messages and process
  the data.

Below are my questions :

- Will the above approach still represent the REST architecture ?
- What are the downsides of above approach(we are aware of network
  latency) any thing other then network latency ?
- What are the REST architecture benefits will we be missing.

Or can we just say that our approach is the REST architecture done differently ?

Answer (score 0):

You're making 2 major choices, each can be decided separately:

1) Having a single HTTP service

2) Using JMS as the communication between this service and the underlying microservices

Regarding #1, if you do this, you can no longer call your services REST since the whole point of REST is to use HTTP verbs together with your domain objects for a predicable set of endpoints.  GET on /objects/ means the object is being fetched, POST on /objects means a new object is being created, etc...  Now, this is OK, you can do it this way and it can work, though it will be "non-standard".

In fact, you might want to check out GraphQL https://www.howtographql.com/basics/1-graphql-is-the-better-rest/ as its pretty close to what you're trying to do.

These days really either REST or GraphQL seems to be the two popular approaches.

Another way to do REST, if you're looking to simply expose REST services on your domain objects without having to write a lot of code, is Spring Data REST: https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest  and if you're comfortable with Spring already, this should be pretty easy to understand.

For #2, your choice of communication between your single gateway service and the underlying services.  Do most of your calls require synchronous answers, such as a UI asking for data to display in a browser or phone?  If so, JMS is not a good approach.  JMS would be an ok approach if the majority of your services were asyncronous - for example someone submitting a stock trade request.  The UI would just need to know the request was submitted, but it will actually be processed some time later and the result will be fetched asyncronously.

Without knowing much about your application, I would recommend sticking with HTTP between your services for simplicity sake unless there is a good reason to switch to JMS.

Comment: Thank you @Michael most of my questions are answered

Comment: That's great to hear.  Would you mind please accepting the answer?